# Spotfire Apply Multi-select values from a property control to a filter using a script

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to figure out how to allow the user to select multiple values from a Property Control, and have those values passed to a filter.

The filtering needs to be conditional for two different related tables, so I have to use a list box tied to a property control, and handle the filtering with a script.

I have a current working version that allows for only one selection, but I need to be able to select multiple.

Two tables filtered with All option selected
[image]

Two tables filtered with 1 program selected
[image]

The script I'm using to filter by 1 selection at a time is:

```
 from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import Filters from
 Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import CheckBoxFilter

 Filter1=Document.FilteringSchemes[0].Item[myDataTable].Item[myDataTable.Columns.Item["Program_Name"]].As[CheckBoxFilter]()
 Filter2=Document.FilteringSchemes[0].Item[myDataTable2].Item[myDataTable2.Columns.Item["Program_Name"]].As[CheckBoxFilter]()

 program=Document.Properties["SelectedProgram"]

 Filter1.IncludeEmpty = False  for value in Filter1.Values:  
 Filter1.Uncheck(value)

 Filter2.IncludeEmpty = False for value in Filter2.Values:  
 Filter2.Uncheck(value)

 if program == "All":   Filter1.Check(program)  Filter2.IncludeEmpty =
 False  for value in Filter2.Values:        Filter2.Check(value) if program
 <> "All":  Filter1.Check(program)  Filter2.Check(program)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are multiple values in program.  Add another for loop to parse through each of the selected values

```
for programvalue in program:
   if programvalue == "All":   
     Filter1.Check(programvalue)  
     Filter2.IncludeEmpty = False  
     for value in Filter2.Values:        
       Filter2.Check(value) 
   if programvalue <> "All":  
     Filter1.Check(programvalue)  
     Filter2.Check(programvalue)
```